# Calculate average of lowest values of matrix rows

Tags: r, matrix, average

I have a large matrix, e.g.

```
> mat = matrix(runif(100), ncol = 5)
> mat
             [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
 [1,] 0.264442954 0.6408534 0.76472904 0.2437074 0.08019882
 [2,] 0.575443586 0.6428957 0.44188123 0.0230842 0.07502289
 [3,] 0.894885901 0.5926238 0.55431966 0.7717503 0.52806173
 [4,] 0.231978411 0.1192595 0.08170498 0.4264405 0.97486053
 [5,] 0.344765840 0.5349323 0.85523617 0.2257759 0.20549035
 [6,] 0.499130844 0.9882825 0.99417390 0.8070708 0.29963075
 [7,] 0.613479990 0.8877605 0.34282782 0.9525512 0.91488004
 [8,] 0.967166001 0.6115709 0.68169111 0.3067973 0.30094691
 [9,] 0.957612804 0.5565989 0.88180650 0.3359184 0.17980137
[10,] 0.342177768 0.7735620 0.48154937 0.3692096 0.31299886
[11,] 0.871928110 0.3397143 0.57596030 0.4749349 0.47800019
[12,] 0.387563040 0.1656725 0.47796646 0.8956274 0.68345302
[13,] 0.628535870 0.3418692 0.86513964 0.8052477 0.01850535
[14,] 0.379472842 0.9176644 0.08829197 0.8548662 0.42151935
[15,] 0.071958980 0.6644800 0.90061596 0.4484674 0.32649345
[16,] 0.229463192 0.9995178 0.63995121 0.8369698 0.35091430
[17,] 0.291761976 0.5014815 0.35260028 0.6188047 0.68192891
[18,] 0.077610797 0.2747788 0.07084273 0.5977530 0.37134566
[19,] 0.675912490 0.6059304 0.29321852 0.5638336 0.73866322
[20,] 0.006010715 0.7697045 0.43627939 0.1723969 0.88665973
```

I want to extract the lowest and highest 2 values of each row and calculate their average.
Eventually, I'd like to generate a new matrix where the first column in the average of the lowest values, and the second column is the average of the highest values. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is more like **please do this for me**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
do.call(rbind, apply(mat,1, function(x)  {sorted = sort(x); 
return(data.frame(min=mean(head(sorted,2)), max=mean(tail(sorted,2))))}))
```

Output:

```
          min       max
1  0.14333229 0.8877635
2  0.12311651 0.5283049
3  0.09367614 0.5433373
4  0.39926848 0.6361645
5  0.05196898 0.5473783
6  0.12876148 0.6153546
7  0.29893684 0.8436462
8  0.14254481 0.7023039
9  0.20889814 0.8863141
10 0.44838327 0.8641790
11 0.14859312 0.5533045
12 0.19728414 0.8619284
13 0.37049481 0.7448965
14 0.30070570 0.9320575
15 0.30333510 0.6774024
16 0.21908982 0.7077274
17 0.61804571 0.9239816
18 0.36525615 0.8531795
19 0.22751108 0.4993744
20 0.14251095 0.6353147
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Florian, this does the job. You made me learn about the rbind function in two posts! ;)

Comment: That's great, I learned something new from the answers on your last question as well so that makes two of us ;)